# Make multiple twilio calls one after the other (ie put them in a queue)

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

What is the correct way to automate the process of making multiple twilio calls. I've tried using a for loop and inputting the phone numbers but that doesn't work as it seems twilio allows only have active call at a time. This is what my code looks like:

```
    Contacts myContacts = new Contacts();
    String[] contactList = null;
    try {
        contactList = myContacts.getContacts();//gets all my contacts
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Calls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "**********"));//I'd like to do this with all my contacts one after the other
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "**********"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Method", "GET"));

    CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();
    Call call = null;
    try {
        call = callFactory.create(params);
    } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've looked at some twilio documentation and this doesn't really seem clear to me. I Hope this is not a silly question and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Twilio allows you to generate [one call per second](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183648-Sending-and-Receiving-Limitations-on-Calls-and-SMS-Messages). Can you share a bit more of your code as the part you've shown just refers to the list of parameters needed to make a call?

Comment: Edited my post, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't appear to be using a loop at all. I'm not sure what your `contactList` array actually has in it, as you have it as an array of strings, but if I can assume those strings are phone numbers then this should work:

```
Contacts myContacts = new Contacts();
String[] contactList = null;
try {
    contactList = myContacts.getContacts();//gets all my contacts
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Calls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();

for (String contact : contactList) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", contact));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Method", "GET"));

    Call call = null;
    try {
        call = callFactory.create(params);
    } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note, I am looping through the `contactList` and creating a new set of parameters each time, filling in the `To` parameter with the contact. I then make the call within the for loop too.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: hii, Im troubling with the same problem in Twilio PHP rest api to make calls in queue, I've tried looping of but it dials simultaneously to all the contacts at the same time, I need to dial one after other . Do you have any suggestions for this problem? Thank You.

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala If you want to make one call after another then it's a bit more complicated. You would need to trigger the next call from the `statusCallback` webhook for the previous call. If you need more detail than that, I'd recommend asking a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @philnash Thank you for the response. Yes my sample didn't have a loop, had removed it. I had just assumed there was a better way of achieving this that wasnt looping though a list. Thanks again.

Comment: The API doesn't do batch jobs, so if you want to make more than one call then you need to loop on your side.